# LINQ and result set mapping in class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

here is the code

```
        var customers = db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(@"SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, 
   Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax
   FROM   dbo.Customers
   WHERE  City = {0}", "London");

foreach (Customer c in customers)
   Console.WriteLine(c.ContactName);
```

code execute sql and retun a customer record. my question how result can be stored in customer class automatically....which i do not understand. if u see this line of code 
`db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>` from here we can understand that customer result will be return and customer data will be stored in customer class. how automatically data can be stored & assign to right property in customer class because a customer class `CustomerID` property name could be CustID....then what will happen.

the line `db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>` is very confusing for me and i just do not understand a new customer instance will be created with return customer data....so plzz discuss in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteQuery` just runs arbitrary SQL (after applying `string.Format`-esque parameterization) and then materializes the `IDataReader` results as a sequence of objects.

Note that the mappings between *mapped* types and the db-columns/type-members is well defined by the data-context (*usually* via attributes on the members, but not always), but IIRC `ExecuteQuery` **does not** apply these mapping (I'm happy to be corrected here). You can inspect this via `db.Mapping.GetMetaType(typeof(Customer))`.

The fundamentals here are no different to if you executed

```
var cust = db.Customers.ToList();
```

except the `db.Customers` version can apply more mappings etc.

The *materialization itself* (i.e. creating the object and setting members) is an example of reflection and meta-programming; most ORMs and micro-ORMs will work pretty much the same there: inspect the type (`Customer` above) and inspect the fields in the reader - and then build some code on-the-fly (usually cached) that will create the new objects and set the members.